# How to get the action name of an MVC action from within another action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 and I would like to know the custom name I gave to an action in a controller from another action within the same controller.

Other than storing the short name of the action in a variable myself or getting it using reflection by finding the ActionName attribute on all actions within the controller type, is there a better way to get this name?

Please consider this example.

```
class FooController : Controller
{
  [ActionName("shortName")]
  public ActionResult LongActionNameIDoNotWantToExposeInTheUri()
  {
  }

  public ActionResult AnotherAction()
  {
    // This make the Uri as 
    // /Foo/LongActionNameIDoNotWantToExposeInTheUri
    // Instead, I want it to be /Foo/shortName
    // I can, of course, hardcode or store the short name
    // in a variable and get it but is there a better way?
    var url = Url.Action("LongActionNameIDoNotWantToExposeInTheUri", "Foo");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just try  var url=Url.Action("shortName", "Foo"). Hope it will work

Comment: @malkam That's exactly what I meant by "I could store it in a variable, but is there a better way."

Comment: You have to recompile to change the action name, so why not just hard code it? Once you override the actions method name with the ActionName attribute, you can't call the action by the method name anyway. i.e. once you've shortnamed you can no longer call via longname. For obvious reasons an action can only have one name. So in short the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Had you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Type controllerType = typeof(FooController);
string actionMethodName = "LongActionNameIDoNotWantToExposeInTheUri";
MethodInfo methodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(actionMethodName);

var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionNameAttribute), false);
string actionName = string.empty;
if (attributes.Length > 0)
{
    actionName = ((ActionNameAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
}
```

or if you want to use it with a method

```
public string GetActionName(Controller controller, string actionMethodName)
{
  Type controllerType = controller.GetType();
  MethodInfo methodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(actionMethodName);

  var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionNameAttribute), false);
  if (attributes.Length > 0)
  {
      return ((ActionNameAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
  }
  else
  {
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("This controller doesnt have Action Name");
  }
}

// if you are in the Controller class
string actionName = GetActionName(this, "LongActionNameIDoNotWantToExposeInTheUri");
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I meant by doing it myself using reflection. I was wondering if there was some help MVC provided.